# Converting Vuetify 1.x v-slot activator to 2.x via v-data-table

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-data-table, v-slot

I have a piece of working code from Veutify 1.5.6 that includes an icon inside of a data table that, when clicked, displays a menu. When clicked the activator shows the list that was activated.

I have a codepen with [this example](https://codepen.io/stephsince93/pen/RwLBwGG)

I want the same functionality, but Vuetify 2 does not have `slot="activator"`.

It looks like they use `v-slot:activator="{ on }"` with a template tag, but I can't get this replicated over.

This is my attempt at it.

```js
<v-data-table
  :headers="labels"
  :items="data"
  >
  <template v-slot:[`item.statusIcon`]="{ item }">
    <td style="cursor: pointer;">
      <v-icon :class="item.status">{{item.statusIcon}}
          <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
              <v-list>
                  <v-list-item
                  v-on="on"
                  v-for="(status, index) in statusItems"
                  :key="index"
                  :class="status.title"
                  @click="setStatus(item, status.title)"
                  >{{ status.title }}></v-list-item>
              </v-list>
          </template>
      </v-icon>
    </td> 
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

There's definitely something small I'm missing and I know that the v-icon should be under the template, but I keep getting this error

> 'v-slot' directive must be owned by a custom element, but 'td', 'div', 'template' is not

I found this [thread](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/6866), but still no help.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap the icon with `v-menu` component then use this icon as menu activator :

```
<v-menu offset-y>
       <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
         <v-icon   v-on="on" :class="item.status">{{item.statusIcon}}
         </v-icon>
        </template>
        <v-list>
                  <v-list-item
                
                  v-for="(status, index) in statusItems"
                  :key="index"
                  :class="status.title"
                  @click="setStatus(item, status.title)"
                  >{{ status.title }}></v-list-item>
        </v-list>
</v-menu>
```

Comment: Where do I use the attrs instance? also, with this solution the icon does not display, just the text

Comment: Nvm I see you just didnt add the inital template and td wrappers. Thanks for this! Question though, what does the attrs value do?

Comment: it passes the attributes from to the activator as done with listener (on) but it's not necessary here